# VC++: Help to create a simple COM class

Tags: com, visual-c++

Can someone guide me on how to create a simple COM class with VC++ that I can have it called by a VB6 app with CreateObject?

Thanks!

Comment: To get very far, you'll need to define more of what you want. Just for example, you can create a COM object using raw C++, MFC or ATL, but there's a fair amount of difference between the three.

Comment: maybe raw c++ is better? I don't want to have many dependencies to this dll because all it'll have to do is return a double number, just for a single method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use "raw C++" there's an unbelievable number of tedious details you need to take care of, even for just a basic COM class. By far the simplest way to create a COM-callable class in C++ is with ATL, which even comes with a wizard (at least in VS 2005 and 2008) for that purpose. The wizard will spit out a perfectly usable coclass including ref counting, registration, and one custom interface. Keep in mind that VB uses late binding, so you're gonna need to implement `IDispatch` on your class (you can use ATL's `IDispatchImpl` to simplify your life somewhat).

BTW, ATL gives you a very small footprint (it's a template library) - just the VC++ runtime, so not many dependencies.